# IntelliJ - Is it possible to differentiate between a Class and an Interface?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

My previous company used to prefix interfaces with an `I`. For instance: `ICar`. I found that useful as the answer to whether a class was an interface or a concrete class was 0 clicks away. My current company, however, does not adopt that rule and just name the interfaces normally, without prefixing it with anything. Now if I come across this type of code:

```
Car car = new Tesla();
```

I have to go into the Car class to know if it is an interface or a class. I find that pretty annoying. Is there a way to make the IDE (in this case Android Studio/IntelliJ) to color/style those in a different way? (Much like they do with fields, i.e., fields are coloured in purple so you know you are not dealing with a local variable instead).

Comment: Also useful is to use the "implementations" command (I think normally mapped to ctrl-alt-b on a Windows PC). If you click on Car and press ctrl-alt-b it will jump to the implementation and ignore the interface. If there are multiple implementations, it will prompt you for which one to navigate to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File → Settings, then in the sidebar select Editor → Color Scheme → Language Defaults.

Expand "Classes" and you will be able to apply custom styling options to Classes and Interfaces. (I personally color class names light blue and interface names green to match their icons in IntelliJ.)

If you want to color Abstract classes and Enum classes uniquely as well, you can do so under the "Java" section, rather than "Language Defaults".

Comment: You can also differentiate between `Static`, `Enum`, etc. Most of them have a separate setting you can change.